# $this->Session->read('Config') prints nothing in cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp

while I try to print `$this->Session->read('Config')` , it prints nothing.

I am using cakephp 2.5.3

I searched from net ,read many blogs, posts and comments and tried to solve it out but my problem still persists.Though `$this->Session->setFlash()` works fine but other session values are not working.

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Session','RequestHandler');


    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        debug($this->Session->read('Config'));//null
        debug($this->Session->read('Config.userAgent'));//null
        debug($this->request->clientIp());// ::1

    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be `$this->session`, with lower `s`?

Comment: CakePHP 2.9 does not exist. The latest 2.x version is 2.5.3 for now :-)

Comment: what do you get if you just try `debug($this->Session->read());`?

Comment: it prints the line no and null

Comment: Are you writing anything to Session? Maybe you want `Configure::read()` instead.

Comment: @IpsitaRout please up-vote the answer also. Thanks. Now you have that much point for up-voting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 please check that at the time of login you create a session or not.
```

that is $this->Session->write('variable name','variable value').
 if you didn't do this you will get null through your code.
 the same code give me information about logged-in user in my system.
 So be sure that you have created a session, 
at the time of login with some variable name and value combination.
 please have a look on this:-

```
public function login() {

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $user_detail = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('username'=>$this->request->data['User']['username'], 'password'=>$this->Auth->password($this->request->data['User']['password'])),'recursive'=> -1,'fields'=>array('deleted'))); // gettin user details
            if(isset($user_detail) && !empty($user_detail)){
                if($user_detail['User']['deleted']== '0'){
                    if ($this->Auth->login()) {// checking user is authorize for login or not?
                        $this->Session->write('user_role', $this->Auth->user('role_id'));// if yes create session variable with the given variable name and value.
                        $is_incharge = $this->check_incharge($this->Auth->user('id'));
                        if ($is_incharge) {
                            $this->Session->write('is_user_incharge', true);
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->write('is_user_incharge', false);
                        }
                        $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid User name or Password.'));
                        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logoutRedirect);
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are deleted.Can not login.'));
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logoutRedirect);
                }
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid User name or Password..'));
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->logoutRedirect);
            }
        }
    }
```